# Getting error while packing my kivy code to an android app

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

***I was packing my kivy code for android using buildozer, but it gave me an error. Since I am very new to Kivy and Android Development. I need your help to understand the problem, and a way to fix the problem.***

The SDK and NDK are stored in my home directory.

***Thank You for giving your valuable time.***

**ERROR:**

```
[INFO]:    -> running autogen.sh
           working: /home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/...(and 42 more)  Exception in thread background thread for pid 20799:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127: 

  RAN: /home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                      
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 213, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 40, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 953, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 879, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127: 

  RAN: /home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=test --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,random --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/kali/Desktop/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1682,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1682'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/9ac82a0b_2bf2_49e5_9c24_5a668104795a'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1655'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'GNOME'
#     LANG = 'en_IN'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     USER = 'kali'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'gnome'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     HOME = '/home/kali'
#     PWD = '/home/kali/Desktop/test'
#     COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT = '1'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=069f8a0bf2d69f8c45bed43960a3d709'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'gnome'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6203'
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.272'
#     LOGNAME = 'kali'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     SHELL = '/usr/bin/zsh'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PATH = '/home/kali/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/kali/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin'
#     _JAVA_OPTIONS = '-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'
#     USERNAME = 'kali'
#     POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT = '1'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_IN'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'qt5ct'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=069f8a0bf2d69f8c45bed43960a3d709'
#     DISPLAY = ':1'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     GDMSESSION = 'gnome'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/kali/Desktop/test'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_mb = '\x1b[1;31m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_md = '\x1b[1;36m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_me = '\x1b[0m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_so = '\x1b[01;33m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_se = '\x1b[0m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_us = '\x1b[1;32m'
#     LESS_TERMCAP_ue = '\x1b[0m'
#     _ = '/home/kali/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/kali/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/kali/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/kali/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from random import randint
from kivy.clock import Clock


class test(App):
    second_passed = 0

    def build(self):
        self.color_variable = ()
        return Label(text='')

    # dt means delta-time
    def my_callback(dt):
        test.second_passed += 1
        App.get_running_app().color_variable = (randint(0, 255)/255,
                                                randint(0, 255)/255, randint(0, 255)/255, 1)

        # Setting the color change to the root window
        Window.clearcolor = App.get_running_app().color_variable

    # call my_callback every 1 seconds
    Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 1)


test().run()
```

Comment: I think your answer is there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770170/13591002 .

Comment: Thank You @ALWIEZ

Answer (score 0):

***This error was given because I was missing some packages that are required by the buildozer.***

```
The missing pakages are :

automake

autoconf

libltdl-dev
```

To solve these issue please run the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install automaker

sudo apt-get install autoconf

sudo apt-get install libltdl-dev
```